# Android: WebView - Open Links

Tags: android

I'm new with Android, so maybe someone can help me.

I have loaded an external URL in `WebView`. 
I want that the links from my site `http://www.domanin.com/about.php` to open in `WebView` and the external link `http://www.anotherdomanin.com/sample.php` to open in default browser.

My code:

`@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        MyWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        MyWeb.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        MyWeb.loadUrl("http://www.domanin.com");
    }`

Comment: `MyWeb.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(false);`

Comment: is not working. all links open in default browser.